# Access UI controls between partial classes

Tags: wpf, class

In my XAML I have a Button, with a button click event. I initialize the component in my MainWindow class : RibbonWindow. I have a the Button Click function in a separate class, but error window gives me "FooApplication.MainWindow" does not contain a definition for fooBtn_Click", below is my code

```
namespace FooApplication1 {
    public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }


/* in another .cs class file located in the same project */
    namespace FooApplication1
    {
        public partial class Jenny : MainWindow
        {        
            public void btnApplyL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            }
        }    
    }
```

I tried to give Jenny a RibbonWindow partial, thinking it might be the issue, but gives error. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XAML file needs to point to the class responsible for the event handling via the `class` attribute.

```
x:Class="FooApplication1.Jenny"
```

Defining event handlers within the XAML forces the use of the `class` attribute as it will dictate where the handlers exist. You can still have the partial classes; it's just that the XAML needs to know which class is responsible for the event handling which modifying the `class` attribute will address.

In addition you will need to move the `InitializeComponent();` call from the `MainWindow` class to the `Jenny` class.

```
    public partial class Jenny : MainWindow
    {        
        public Jenny()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

        ...
    }
```

Comment: that way my Jenny Class have access to the button function, but I also have button function in my MainWindow Class, which cannot be defined if my InitializeCompenet() is in Jenny. I cannot have two x:Class attribute in my XAML. What shall I do then?

Comment: @KMC You can only point to one class via the class attribute. Not sure of your reasoning for needing to do this...there may be better way